# Can $\lim_{x \to \infty} = \frac{x^2}{x-1}$ be solved without L'hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to find limit for:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} = \frac{x^2}{x-1}$$

I could solve this easily with L'hopital's rule. Taking derivative of both numerator and denumatorator gives:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} = \frac{2x}{1} = \infty$$

But is there a way to solve this without using it? I tried multiplying both parts of the fraction with conjugate $(x+1)$, and then dividing with largest element. But I get zero in the denumerator.

Comment: Just show it (eventually) exceeds some function of $x$ which goes to $+\infty$, such as $f(x)=x$

Comment: Observe that $\frac{x^2}{x - 1} = x + 1 + \frac{1}{x - 1}$.

Comment: There is a typo: the derivative of $x-1$ is $1$, not $-1$.

Comment: @Taladris Thank you, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, and for such simple problems, L’Hopital’s rule should never be used. When dealing with limits of rational functions (polynomial divided by polynomial), you always factor the highest powers from the numerator and denominator:
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{x-1}=\frac{x^2\cdot(1)}{x\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}=x\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}.
\end{align}
As $x\to\infty$, the first term which is just $x$ obviously approaches $\infty$. The fraction on the other hand approaches $\frac{1}{1-0}=1$. Hence, their product approaches $\infty$.

This reasoning will show you more generally that if $f(x)=\frac{a_nx^n+\dots +a_0}{b_mx^m+\cdots +b_0}$ is a rational function with $a_n,b_m\neq 0$, then

- $n>m$ implies that
  $
  \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\begin{cases}
  \infty &\text{if $\frac{a_n}{b_m}>0$}\\
  -\infty & \text{if $\frac{a_n}{b_m}<0$}.
  \end{cases}
  $
- $n=m$ implies that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$.
- $n<m$ implies that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

Comment: I just started learning limits, can I ask why L’Hopital’s rule should not be used in simple cases?

Comment: @LennyWhite L’Hopital’s rule is a theorem of great power. With great power comes great responsibility :) The problem is not a logical one, it’s more of a pedagogical one. The more a beginning student of calculus uses L’Hopital’s rule, the more I (and every calc teacher I have ever spoken to) have found that their brain turns to mush. They only know that one rule, and can’t compute limits any other way. Algebraic methods, like factoring, squeeze theorem etc are much more versatile, so you need to know how to use them (for which you need to practice them more :)

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Comment: Also, L’Hopital’s is special to 1D, so doesn’t generalize to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

If we multiply the numerator and denominator by the reciprocal of the highest power of $x$ in the denominator, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{x - 1} & = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{x - 1} \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}\\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{1 - \frac{1}{x}}\\
& = \infty
\end{align*}
since the numerator grows without bound while the denominator approaches $1$.

Alternatively, observe that
$$\frac{x^2}{x - 1} = x + 1 + \frac{1}{x - 1} > x + 1$$
whenever $x > 1$.  Hence,
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{x - 1} \geq \lim_{x \to \infty} (x + 1) = \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

It can be graphically understood,
$f(x)=x^2$ is a highly increasing function for larger values of $x$
[since $f'(x)=2x$, $x$ increases $f'(x)$ increases]

Whereas $g(x)=x-1$ has constant $g'(x)=1$

Therefore when $x$ tends to infinity the expression
$f(x)/g(x)$ tends to infinity

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$\frac{x^{2}}{x-1} = \frac{x^{2}-1+1}{x-1} = \frac{x^{2}-1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x-1} = x+1 + \frac{1}{x-1}.$$
The first limit goes to infinity and the second goes to zero, so the result is:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{x-1} = +\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

Choose some value of N.  Assume that N is large (like at least 7).

If $x>N$ then $\frac {x^2}{x-1} > N$

Now assume that N is even bigger than that!  The previous statement still holds.  And, it holds for $N$ arbitrarily large.